Multiple web applications on same site in Azure
I have an ASP.NET Core Web App running on Azure, and I see a need for exposing the underlying data as a separate ASP.NET Core Web API. I'd like to host these on the same site:

Web App: https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net
Web API: https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api

Is this even possible, or do I need to look into hosting them side by side on different hosts?

Web App: https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net
Web API: https://mywebsite-api.azurewebsites.net


Refer this SOThread

Why can't you simply do CNAME/A mapping and point the same WebApp to multiple domains? It is similar to pointing same web app to https://mywebapp.com and https://www.mywebapp.com.

@Harshitha I'm using VS Code, so I don't really have access to the Visual Studio features. I'm currently relying on GitHub Actions to publish my stuff: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy, specifically the DotNet variant: https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AppService/asp.net-core-webapp-on-azure.yml

Refer this SOThread

@Harshitha - if that other Stack Overflow post answers the same question, then this question should be marked as a duplicate.
